# Does adding a contact and user to an account trigger an update to that account?

Tags: trigger, customer-community

I am trying to fire a trigger on the account when IsCustomerPortal if flipped to true. I have checked in workbench and this field is definitely changing when I add a new user and contact but it doesn't seem to be firing the after update. Is there some way to capture this event?

Comment: Is the field appearing in trigger.new and trigger.old for evaluation as a criteria for comparison? It would seem that it's the act of inserting a User that's triggering the event and that's what you'd want your trigger to fire on. I don't know what subsequent workflow it is that later updates Account. I'd expect you could detect when inserting a User, then query for the change in Account from there.